# Where in Old Testament is said something like we must be cautious reading it because prophets can make mistakes?

Tags: old-testament

A week ago I was reading Matthew, and at Mt 2:15 and 2:17 he write about Old Testament prophecies. Searching for it, maybe in Jeremiah, I read something like  *'**we must be cautious reading the Holy Scriptures because prophets can make mistakes**'*. I found it a beautiful message, but at the time, when I was searching for the prophecy referenced by Matthew, I don't pay too much attention to it, and today I'm not able to find it again.
Can someone point me the location of some versicle that could be that?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). I looked up Matthew 1:15, 17, and they are verses in a genealogy rather than references to Old Testament prophecies. Can you give us the correct verses you were referring to? Also, about asking questions here, please see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and: [How do I ask a good question?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @LeeWoofenden , I'm sorry, it is Matthew 2:15,17. I'll edit may question.

Comment: Can you  tell us what Bible version you are using?

Comment: @DickHarfield it's a Catholic Bible, in Portuguese, from 1962, _IMPRIMATUR_ given by _Curia Archiepiscopalis Mediolani_.

Answer (score 1):

I think the passage you are asking about is:

> Jeremiah 14:13 through 17 KJV  Then said I, Ah, Lord GOD! behold, the prophets say unto them, Ye shall not see the sword, neither shall ye have famine; but I will give you assured peace in this place. 14  Then the LORD said unto me, The prophets prophesy lies in my name: I sent them not, neither have I commanded them, neither spake unto them: they prophesy unto you a false vision and divination, and a thing of nought, and the deceit of their heart. 15  Therefore thus saith the LORD concerning the prophets that prophesy in my name, and I sent them not, yet they say, Sword and famine shall not be in this land; By sword and famine shall those prophets be consumed. 16  And the people to whom they prophesy shall be cast out in the streets of Jerusalem because of the famine and the sword; and they shall have none to bury them, them, their wives, nor their sons, nor their daughters: for I will pour their wickedness upon them. 17  Therefore thou shalt say this word unto them; Let mine eyes run down with tears night and day, and let them not cease: for the virgin daughter of my people is broken with a great breach, with a very grievous blow.

If this is the passage it must be noted that it is referring to ***False Prophets*** as stated in verse 14.

If these are not the verses you are asking about let me know and I will do some more research.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've appreciate your help, but is not this passage. The passage, I remember,  is not about **False Prophets**, but about something like the recognition of the fragility of the prophecies itself by the prophet himself. I guess I read it on Jeremiah, but I'm not 100% sure, but I'm sure it is on the Old Testament.

Comment: @LeandrosLópez I'll do some more research and if I find anything I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any passage where God (through the inspired writers of the Bible) would be saying that true prophets of God or the written word of God itself might be mistaken, so you should pick and choose carefully what you believe.

[Here's a list](https://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?search=prophet%20prophets%20prophecy%20prophecies&version=KJV&searchtype=any&spanbegin=30&spanend=30&limit=100) of all word forms of "prophet" or "prophecy" from Jeremiah.  You'll notice that the theme of almost all these verses is God's condemnation of all the **false** prophets of Judah.  Time and time again God warns his people not to listen to them because He has not sent them.  The clear implication is that true prophets, like Jeremiah, prophecy the true word of God, and therefore refusing to believe them would be foolish.

In fact one of the signs of a true prophet of God is that what he prophecies comes true.  A prophecy that does not come true is a sign of a false prophet.  Read about Jeremiah's encounter with Hananiah in [Jeremiah 28](http://legacy.esvbible.org/search/jer%2B28/) to see how that played out, especially verse 9:

> As for the prophet who prophesies peace, when the word of that prophet comes to pass, then it will be known that the LORD has truly sent the prophet.”
>   (Jeremiah 28:9 ESV)